# Unable to install rmongodb package in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rmongodb

I have installed R 3.02 in Ubuntu 14.04.1. I tried to install a rmongodb package, with the following command

```
install.packages("rmongodb")
```

the response I got was:

```
> install.packages("rmongodb")
Installing package into ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available
trying URL 'http://cran.repo.bppt.go.id/src/contrib/rmongodb_1.8.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1013201 bytes (989 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 989 Kb


The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp99TR5x/downloaded_packages’

> library(rmongodb)
Error in library(rmongodb) : there is no package called ‘rmongodb’
```

**Note:** I have installed the "rmongodb" in my local and I did the above try in EC2 and failed to install the same package.

**EDIT:**

I have just checked out in local the version of R is 3.2 but in server 3.02. Is that gonna be a problem ?

Comment: Use the same versions of development software everywhere. Sooner or later you will run into problems if you don't. There is a reason a lot of languages have version control managers such as rubys rvm or rbenv.

Comment: @isaac9A yep you are right I did install the same version and I have overcome the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was trying to install R with below command, it installs the **R 3.02**

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

I have come across [this link](https://pythonandr.wordpress.com/2015/04/27/upgrading-to-r-3-2-0-on-ubuntu/), which helped me to install latest version of R. Then I have tried installing `install.packages("rmongodb")`, It got installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install also the packages that rmongodb depends on. For that, try:

```
install.packages("rmongodb", dependencies = TRUE)
```